# ¿Que formas hay de imprimir un id?

Tags: php, html, ajax

tengo un **id** que llamo desde ajax para que imprima un php
esto lo tengo en un cuerpo de html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="selector"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

el codigo php es este:

```
<?php 
include_once"../../../includes/conex.php";
IF (isset($_POST['Types'])){
$Types = $_POST['Types'];
echo '<select class="input1" id="Items" name="Item" onclick="buscar();" require/>
                                <option value="">Selecione Un tipo</option>';
$omly=mssql_query('SELECT ItemName,ItemID FROM PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items WHERE Type = \''.$Types.'\' 
AND ItemName Not LIKE \'%??%\' ORDER BY Type ASC');
WHILE ($typeo = mssql_fetch_array($omly)){
        print "<option value='".$typeo['ItemID']."'>".$typeo['ItemName']."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
}
?>
```

el problema que al imprimir me sale esto: de la imagen **¿como lo corrijo?**

[image: Se ve que no da las opciones para selecionar ya que salen por fuera]

Comment: Amigo usted ve el Campo selecion Bien? al llamar la etiqueta ID no se Visualiza el select Option en el cuadro dentro creo que la pregunta es muy clara.

Comment: No entendi la respuesta Igual tienes razon en algo, debo editar mi pregunta para que se entienda todavia mejor gracias y si me ayudas te lo agradesco

Comment: Lo único que veo a primera vista ( que a mi no me da el fallo en los navegadores que he probado, pero igual tu estás en otro ) es, que el `require` deberia de ser `required` y que la `/` que hay justo despues del require, yo la quitaría, porque esa barra es para indicar el cierre del elemento y a lo mejor el navegador no lo interpreta como tu quieres y cuenta los options como si no fuesen de ese select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas imprimiendo en diferentes `echo` el `select`

```html
<?php 
include_once"../../../includes/conex.php";

IF (isset($_POST['Types'])){
  $Types = $_POST['Types'];
  $select = "<select class='input1' id='Items' name='Item' onclick='buscar();' require>
      <option value="">Selecione Un tipo</option>';
  $omly=mssql_query('SELECT ItemName,ItemID FROM PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items WHERE      Type = \''.$Types.'\' AND ItemName Not LIKE \'%??%\' ORDER BY Type ASC');
  
WHILE ($typeo = mssql_fetch_array($omly)){
        //Contatenamos las demas opciones a la variable $select
        $select .= "<option value='".$typeo['ItemID']."'>".$typeo['ItemName']."</option>";
}
$select .= '</select>';

echo $select;
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

connect_errno > 0){

    die('Error: No es posible establecer la conexión: [' . $link->connect_error . ']');

}

 

$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

 

$extraerdato = $link->query("SELECT * FROM LA_TABLA where id=$id");

$fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($extraerdato);

$nombre = $fetch['nombre'];

$apellido = $fetch['apellido'];

$email = $fetch['email'];

$fotografia = $fetch['fotografia'];

 

echo "Datos asociados con la id: $id
$nombre
$apellido
$email
";

Comment: _¿Qué hace este código?_ Lee [answer].